# Using WindowsIdentity to connect to ManagementScope(WMI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wmi, windows-identity

I have a .net core application that is hosted on IIS. This application utilizes System.Management to connect to other machines to gather information.

I am noticing that some of my calls are getting an access denied response. The application pool is running as a user that is an admin on the remote machines. However the ManagementScope does not appear to be using the Application pool's identity.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the WindowsIdentity while connecting to the remote machine?

I am looking for something like the following.

```
private ManagementScope GetManagementScope(string machineName)
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
    {
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
        Username = identity.Name 
        // Something here to pass along the password?
    };

    ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath
    {
        Server = machineName,
        NamespacePath = "\\root\\MicrosoftIISv2"
    };

    return new ManagementScope(path, options);
}
```

I have tried hard coding the User name and password and that works fine but I would really like to use the Application pools identity.

Answer (score 0):

I think, and hope, there is no way to retrieve the password.
The only way is to pass it as external parameter and possibly stored in a secure application.

Maybe you can consider to store this secret in Azure Key Vault and retrieve that setting.